# Getting Marking Guides Criterion Scores for Graded User Using Web Services in Moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I'm currently working with Moodle Learning Management System to get student grades for my client's system.

How can I get marking guide criterion assessments/grades of students in moodle using REST API.

> It has four parameters: component: (Required)  --> (Which are the
> possible values besides mod_assign)
>
> contextid (Required)-->(No idea , have tried several values obtained
> from debugging) itemname (Required)-->( This is the parameter that
> generate the exception)

gradeduserid  (Required)

Below is the php file for the API with file path:
/moodle/grade/grading/form/guide/classes/grades/grader/gradingpanel/external/fetch.php

Thank you in advance.
[API Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnSaY.png)

I have attempted to get marking guide criterion assessments/grades of students in moodle using REST API.

The call should be something like this:

```
http://{{domain}}/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken={{token}}&moodlewsrestformat=json&wsfunction=gradingform_guide_grader_gradingpanel_fetch&component=mod_assign&contextid=684&itemname=Assignment1&gradeduserid=182
```

The response I got:

```
{"exception":"coding_exception","errorcode":"codingerror","message":"Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: The 'Assignment1' item is not valid for the 'mod_assign' component"}
```

I'm expecting to see the marking guide criterion scores with the associated graded user ID.